# Views: Showing related nodes from the tagged taxonomy term using views

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have two content types, Article and FAQ. They both have a *Term reference* field for tagging from the same taxonomy vocabulary called subject.

So on *Article* node view page, I want to display the three latest *FAQ* nodes that are tagged the same taxonomy term as to the currently displayed *Article* node, using views.

Please give me some idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create view (block)
2. Add fields (title)
3. Add Contextual filters: "Content: Has taxonomy term ID"
4. Configuration on this filter:

   1. When the filter value is NOT in the URL
   2. Provide default value
   3. Type: Taxonomy Term ID from URL. Under that, check the box "*Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks.*" Check the boxes of the taxonomies you want involved here
5. Filter criteria: Content: Type (= FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to set up a similar view like this while the 1st relationship find all tags under one node, and the 2nd relationship find all content with this tags, including the existing content.

However, you may need to change the field type in content type as "entity reference" rather than "term reference" to make it work[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please try to keep your screenshots at / under 630px width, or as close to it as feasible. You know, for readability. With 630px or less, we avoid downscaling and it's easier to read texts on screenshot.